# isDate($date) in prestashop complaining as Invalid date for DATE_FORMAT(a.date_add, "%d-%b-%Y %h:%i:%s %p")

Tags: php, regex, prestashop

I want  this  `29-Jun-2016 11:47:54 AM`, format in my prestashop grid

If I remove the colon before the seconds isDate function works fine ie `DATE_FORMAT(a.date_add, "%d-%b-%Y %h:%i%s %p")`. But if the colon is there it validates error

Below is my isDate Validate function:

```
/**
 * Check for date validity
 *
 * @param string $date Date to validate
 * @return bool Validity is ok or not
 */
public static function isDate($date)
{
    if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})-((?:0?[0-9])|(?:1[0-2]))-((?:0?[0-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[01]))( [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})?$/', $date, $matches)) {
        return false;
    }
    return checkdate((int)$matches[2], (int)$matches[3], (int)$matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just format without colon and add the colon in template? Is this front end or backoffice table/grid?

Comment: back office  grid ,in  back office how can I add that in template ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the pre-defined PrestaShop function to format date.

```
Tools::displayDate($any_date, $this->context->language->id, true);
```

And you can set the date format for different languages by editing any language from your admin panel (Localization -> Languages -> Edit any Language)

Comment: Ok   but now  my problem is   when  i export the file to csv the date format changes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works for you without colon, because there is nothing about `[a-z]` characters, like Jun or AM, in regular expression.

`idDate` method can validate e.g. date-time stored in DB. You can get `date_add`, validate it and then:
`date('d-M-Y h:i:s A', $date_add);`

Comment: explain what do you expect to have in that code. What is your problem?

Comment: @JerryAbraham In `formatMyDate()` use `return DateTime::createFromFormat($value, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')->format('%d-%b-%Y %h:%i:%s %p');` but I still don't see where are you using `isDate` validation in your code or where is the problem.

Comment: the problem is when I  call the controller page itself I am having issue Invalid date
at line 881 in file classes/Tools.php  - Its giving me error  invalid date format